# Merging the result of two prpt reports into one PDF in pentaho report designer

Tags: pdf, pentaho

I have been looking all over for this. I have two seperate prpt files and I am able to generate the pdf's for these prpt files. I would like to combine both the reports into a single PDF with two pages. I would like to do this either in Report Designer or in Pentaho Data Integration. Please can someone help me out with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via a subreport in Report Designer - no need to use the DI tool. You create a new subreport in the parent report, then paste in all the elements from the child. Not very clean admittedly.

Alternatively if it's a very complex report you can unzip the prpt, insert the child report and re-zip it.  But this is tricky - and there's some constraints about what must be done where!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually got this to work using the sub-report technique and had to add it under the main report.

Answer (score 0):

If your sole purpose is to merge the pdf documents (and not the prpt files): There is a free open source tool called [**pdfsam**](http://www.pdfsam.org/) which is capable of merging multiple pdf documents. Alternatively and if you are not reluctant to upload maybe sensitive data you could use an online service, e.g. [mergepdf by foxyutils](http://foxyutils.com/mergepdf/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply..I was looking to automate the process. I dont think I would want to manually merge the pdf's together which is why I wanted to do this in the Pentaho Report designer or using the Data Integration tool itself.